# Onkeypress function returning spaces instead of letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, onkeypress

I am using the following in and attempt to get a user's letter guess to appear on screen, but when I check the devtools the keypress is being returned to the array like [ , , , , , ,]. No letters. Ideas?

```js
var letguessText = document.getElementById("letguess")
var guessArray = []

document.onkeypress = function(event) {
  var guess = event.key

  guessArray.push(String.fromCharCode(guess));
  letguessText.textContent = guessArray;
}
```

Comment: I think you want to use this?
 guessArray.push(guess);

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need fromCharCode as the event.key is the character. Here is an example.

```js
var letguessText = document.getElementById("letguess")
var guessArray = []

document.onkeypress = function(event) {
  var guess = event.key
  guessArray.push(guess);
  letguessText.textContent = guessArray;
}
```

```html
<p id="letguess">Start typing</p>
```